# JPA eclipselink oracle db error: not a selected expression

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

```
Order                 OrderItem                                     Product
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                    id,orderId,proudctId,unitPrice,quantity       id, barcode
```

JPA eclipseLink: list order items order by orderId, product barcode, and quantity:

```
select * from OrderItem order by orderId asc, 
lpad(product.barcode, 20, '0') desc, quantity asc

Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=OrderItem sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*,
ROWNUM rnum  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID AS a1, t1.QUANTITY AS a2, 
t1.UNITPRICE AS a3, t1.orderId AS a4, t1.productId AS a5, lpad(t0.barcode, ?, ?)
FROM Product t0, OrderItem t1 WHERE (t0.ID = t1.productId) ORDER BY t1.orderId 
ASC, lpad(t0.barcode, ?, ?) DESC, t1.QUANTITY ASC) a WHERE ROWNUM <= ?) WHERE 
rnum > ?")
```

ERROR ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

If executing the SQL in oracle sqlPlus, no error. If simply order by product.barcode instead of lpad(...), it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to order by the same expression `lpad(p.barcode, ?, ?)`, use its alias instead. Try this:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*,
        ROWNUM rnum
    from (
        select distinct o.ID as a1,
            o.QUANTITY as a2,
            o.UNITPRICE as a3,
            o.orderId as a4,
            o.productId as a5,
            lpad(p.barcode, ?, ?) as a6
        from Product p
        join OrderItem o on p.ID = o.productId
        order by a4,
            a6 desc,
            a2
        ) a
    where ROWNUM <= ?
    )
where rnum > ?
```

Also notice the *explicit* join syntax which modern and clearer than the old comma based join syntax and the renamed aliases for the tables.